# why my mac has installed gem

Tags: macos, rubygems, installation

My mac is 10.9.1, and it has installed Xcode. when I open the shell and type "gem", it present the info like

> ```
> RubyGems is a sophisticated package manager for Ruby.  This is a
> basic help message containing pointers to more information.
>
>   Usage:
>     gem -h/--help
>     gem -v/--version
>     gem command [arguments...] [options...]
> ```

so I think my mac has installed the gem , but why, I has never install it since I buy it.

Answer (score 0):

Mac OS X comes bundled with a version of ruby pre-installed. And that includes the rubygems utility app, which is invoked as 'gem'.